# getNewAddress error Error: Invalid Response In IOTA

Tags: node

[![it try to generate the address for transition of bit-coin but very time show the in valid responses and i am using sandbox  for transition [![const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js')
var iota = new IOTA({
  'provider': 'https://sandbox.iota.org/api/v1/',
  'sandbox': true,
});

iota.api.getNodeInfo((error, nodeInfo) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('getNodeInfo error', error)
    } else {
        console.log('getNodeInfo result', nodeInfo)
    }
});

var seed = "here is the seed";

iota.api.getNewAddress(seed, (error, address) => {
   if (error) {
       console.error('getNewAddress error', error)
   } else {
       console.log('new address generated: ' + address)
   }
})
 ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf3ZX.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf3ZX.png) ][2]][2]